# Neo4j import csv with spliting values in a column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, neo4j, cypher

I want to the following data to a neo4j database. The column "friends" is a string of ids separated by ",". So, there should be 10 nodes (id of 1-10) where only 5 of them I know about their ages. And I want to have relationship between each id and their friends.

Example dataframe

```
id age friends
1   10  "3,2"
2   20  "1,6"
3   15  "4,5,10"
4   13  "2,8,9"
5   25  "1,4,7"
```

My code using is

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df.csv' AS line
MERGE (User {id: line.id, age: line.age})

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df.csv' AS line
UNWIND split(line.friends, ',') AS friends
MERGE (u:User {id: friends})

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df.csv' AS line
UNWIND split(line.friends, ',') AS friends
With line, friends
MERGE (User1{id: line.id})-[:FRIENDS]->(User2{id: friends})
```

Is it the correct way to do it? And how to simplify the code?

Answer (score 1):

A `foreach` should do it:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///df.csv' AS line
MERGE (u:User {id: line.id}) SET u.age=toInteger(line.age)
WITH u,line,split(line.friends, ',') AS friends
FOREACH (f in friends | merge (friend:User {id: f}) merge (u)-[:FRIENDS]->(friend))
```

All values are Strings, so you will need to convert to other data types if required (see age).